# Как вставить текст посередине другого

Tags: python, html, файлы

У меня есть переменная

```
a = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>hello world</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>hello</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
```

как мне добавить допустим `<!-->Hello world</!-->`
в `a`

чтобы на выходе я получил

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <!-->Hello world</!-->
         <title>hello world</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>hello</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Возможно вам следует обратить внимание на шаблонизаторы. Например [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```
print(a.replace("<head>", "<head><!-->Hello world</!-->"))
```

Comment: Это же просто заменит текст между <title></title>

Comment: поправил. извините